# Batch Script - Most recent folder and name containing

Tags: batch-file, directory

I am trying to create a script that will check a directory for folders that are most recent (latest folders created) and only containing certain word / characters

I have a been able to find how to find the most recent folder within the directory (code below), however I am not sure on how to get the most recent folder but only containing a certain word

So for example I only want the most recent folder in the directory but that folder must contain the word "web" for example even if there are more recent folders in the directory with other file names

Can someone help me please and build on what I currently have to allow me to find the most recent folder in a directory that contains word "web"

```
REM Check most recent folder in a directory :-
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir " directory " /AD /O-D /B') do (set recent=%%A& goto line)
:line
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost done. If the folder has to contain a text, filter the output of `dir` command. Use
`find` or `findstr`.

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /AD /O-D /B "directory" ^| find /i "web" ') do (set "recent=%%A"& goto line)
:line
```